# Rails, element show and page updates

Tags: element, show, ruby-on-rails

I have a series of `div`s, and each one has a delete link. Each one also has a currently hidden spinner image. Idea is that when the delete link is pressed (and the object in the `div` is being deleted), the spinner is displayed. Once the AJAX call to delete the object is done, then the `div` item is removed from the series.

My problem here is basically getting the spinner image to display.

This is the code I am using:

```
  def destroy_object(object)
    update_page do |page|
      page.show "spinner-del-#{object.id}"
    end
    remote_function(
      :url => url_for(object),
      :method => :delete
    )
  end
```

The remote_function portion calls an rjs which removes the relevant `div` properly, so that's not an issue. However, the `update_page` section to show the spinner isn't working, and I really can't figure out why.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to use the `:before` option that is part of the `remote_function` call, and it worked.

```
  def destroy_object(object)
    remote_function(
      :url => url_for(object),
      :method => :delete,
      :confirm => "Are you sure you wish to delete?",
      :before => "Element.show('spinner-del-#{object.id}')"
    )
  end
```

Yay!